# Macbook Pro 8,1 not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

A week ago, I found an old **MacBook Pro 8,1** (13” MacBook Pro, Late 2011). It was working fine, but the battery wasn't charging. The charging lights on the side of the MacBook said that it was fully charged, but when I unplugged the charger, it turned off instantly.

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Note: I installed Ubuntu so that it would run faster, but I do have a backup of macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery on that MacBook Pro is dead. You could:

1. Have Apple replace the battery for you. However, since your laptop is most likely out of warranty after 6 years, this will cost you a pretty penny.
2. Buy a replacement battery and replace it yourself using these [instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Battery+Replacement/7649) from iFixit. The procedure is rated as easy and the page includes a video guide.
3. Use that laptop as a desktop replacement (permanently plugged-in). You’ll need to be extra careful to avoid data loss, considering the MagSafe connector will come unplugged very easily. You may consider duct-taping it in place.

Comment: Thanks, Phong! I guess i'll get a new battery and replace it my self.